# C#10: A namespace-scoped Access modifier

Tags: c#, language-features

As in the title, I would love to see this in C#.

```
namespace PrivateStuff; //note: filescope namespace here!

public class PartiallyVisibleOutside
{
   public int A;
   namespace int B;
}

public class Test
{ 
    public PartiallyVisibleOutside NC {get; private set;}

    public void DoSmth()
    { 
        NC.A = 100000 + NC.B;  //OKAY til now!
        Console.Write(NC.A);
    }
}

//
namespace OUTSIDE;

public class OutsideClass 
{
   public PartiallyVisibleOutside Test;

   void DoSmth()
   {
      Test.A = 100; //OKAY
      Test.B = 100; //Compiletime-Error!
   }
}
```

Does smth like this exist? Or shall i open up a feature-request at C#

Comment: Namespaces are to improve the organisation of names, not access.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such feature and I think it is very niche thing to be implemented in near feature. Though you can simulate it by moving `Test` and `PartiallyVisibleOutside` into separate project (assembly) and marking `B` as [`internal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/internal).

Comment: Tbh mate, Java and Delphi has this feature for ages. And I find it to be allowing for more strict seperation of Access. Nothing bad with this imho.

Comment: @Shpendicus - bear in mind that, in Java at least, namespace and "assembly" (package I think is the word) are strongly tied together, at least so far as I understand it. But in .NET, assembly and namespace are orthogonal. Anybody, in any new project, can declare a type in the `System` namespace, as an example.

Comment: mate, i totally forgot to communicate what i truely wanted! Im a fool..                                  its not the class that i do not want outside  filescope to be accessible but rather some of its members! big difference, I just want to further keep a strong semantics in, which says: "do not touch, ANYONE, this member outside, cause you may accidently break it by accessing it otherwise, by accessing that member! And yea even if we are consious beings, you still want the compiler to help you keeping ur hands away from stuff you should not touch.. even tho ppl say, "just dont touch it then?"

Comment: Because by the logic "Dont touch it then" kinda saying, dont exceed the index of a pointer to an array, not that humans can make mistakes and so .

Comment: @Shpendicus - I'm looking at a [Java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) and C# has the same modifiers as Java, except it calls "package-private" `internal`. So I'm not sure where you're seeing something that Java has that C# doesn't.

Comment: Screw java then, but its still something useful IMHO: It just strongly communicates (even to your co-workers or whoever shares the code (not assembly, the raw code) that you just shall not touch some properties, if they are marked with the "namespace" access-modifier, idk, this could really tell the other one "ohh, ok, this must be smth dangerous, if I change that property from the outside... idk. whatever.

Comment: For instance, take "Nullability" , you dont need ACTUALLY this nullable coonotation, that it is allowed to be null, you can "simply" put a comment over your function and thats it, which says "{x} can be null!"